# How to make text blinking without blocking the whole program in C++ Allegro?

Tags: c++, allegro

```
bool running = true;

int width = al_get_display_width(display);
while (running) {

for (;;) {
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255));
    al_draw_bitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 0);
    al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0), 760, 375, 0, "Play (Spacebar)");
    al_flip_display();
    al_rest(1.5);

    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255));
    al_draw_bitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 0);
    al_flip_display();
    al_rest(0.5);
}

ALLEGRO_EVENT event;
al_wait_for_event(queue, &event);
if (event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE) {
    running = false;
}
}
```

As you can see I have this endless loop which blocks the whole program in order for the text to blink. The question is how do I do the blinking so the others things keep working like the event which follows up 
(it's here for the window to close, when the user clicks X)

Comment: Use some kind of timer and draw the blink effect when that timer expires, at all other times do whatever it is your program does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to check which state (blink on or off) to draw when drawing the text. This can be derived from the current time. Something like:

```
while (running) {
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255));
    al_draw_bitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 0);

    if (fmod(al_get_time(), 2) < 1.5) { // Show the text for 1.5 seconds every 2 seconds.
        al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0), 760, 375, 0, "Play (Spacebar)");
    }

    al_flip_display();

    // Handle events in a non-blocking way, for example
    // using al_get_next_event (not al_wait_for_event).
}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, and that's what the code looks like now:
 bool running = true;
 while (running) {

   al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255));
   al_draw_bitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 0);

   if (fmod(al_get_time(), 2) < 1.5) { // Show the text for 1.5 seconds every 2 seconds.
    al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0), 760, 375, 0, "Play (Spacebar)");
   }

   al_flip_display();

   ALLEGRO_EVENT event;
   al_wait_for_event(event_queue, &event);
   if (event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE) {
    running = false;
   }
 }

Surprisingly, it does not work!

Comment: As the text does not blink

Comment: Changed this line: if (event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE) to  if (event.type != ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE) and now when I quickly click the exit button the text is blinking!

Comment: There's some weird behaviour with this event. Do you know why?

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice you had `al_wait_for_event`. This way of blinking expects the drawing to happen continuously so it can redraw when the blink state changes, but `al_wait_for_event` stops the execution until an event has occurred. Try `al_wait_for_event_timed` with a small enough value for the `secs` argument, or `al_get_next_event` to have no waiting happen at all.

Answer (score 1):

Outside your main loop:

1. Create timer: `timer = al_create_timer(...);`
2. Create event queue: `event_queue = al_create_event_queue();`
3. At the top within your main loop:

```
al_wait_for_event(event_queue, &ev);

if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
{
// do your blinking stuff here
}
```